# Derivation of Nielsen and Chuang's Eq. (8.127) and (8.128)

Tags: operators, quantum-information

In subsection 8.3.6 "Phase damping" of Nielsen and Chuang (2010), the Hamiltonian is given as

$$
H = \chi a^\dagger a(b+b^\dagger)
\tag{8.126}\label{8.126}
$$
and $U = \exp(-iH\Delta t)$, with $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are the creation/annihilation operators for system A, $b$ and $b^\dagger$ for system B.  Both system $A$ and $B$ are considered as regular quantum harmonic oscillators.  The operator $U$ is acting on the combined space $A\otimes B$.  The operation element $E_k$, a set of operators acting on the $A$ space, are defined by taking the inner product of $U$ in the $B$ space, $$E_k = \langle k_b|U|0_b\rangle.$$
Then the equation \eqref{8.127} and \eqref{8.128} of Nielsen and Chuang shows the sub-block of $E_0$ and $E_1$ when considering only $|0_a\rangle$ and $|1_a\rangle$,
$$
E_0 = \begin{bmatrix} \langle0_a|E_0|0_a\rangle & \langle0_a|E_0|1_a\rangle \\ \langle1_a|E_0|0_a\rangle & \langle1_a|E_0|1_a\rangle \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{1-\lambda}\end{bmatrix}
\tag{8.127}\label{8.127}
$$
and
$$
E_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \langle0_a|E_1|0_a\rangle & \langle0_a|E_1|1_a\rangle \\ \langle1_a|E_1|0_a\rangle & \langle1_a|E_1|1_a\rangle \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{\lambda}\end{bmatrix},
\tag{8.128}\label{8.128}
$$ where $\lambda = 1-\cos^2(\chi\Delta t)$.

I'm having trouble deriving the matrix elements $\langle1_a|E_0|1_a\rangle$ and $\langle1_a|E_1|1_a\rangle$.

Here is what I have:
$$ \langle1_a|E_0|1_a\rangle = \langle1_a0_b|U|1_a0_b\rangle \\ = \langle1_a0_b|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-i\chi\Delta t)^n}{n!}(a^\dagger a)^n(b+b^\dagger)^n|1_a0_b\rangle \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-i\chi\Delta t)^n}{n!}\langle1_a|(a^\dagger a)^n|1_a\rangle\langle0_b|(b+b^\dagger)^n|0_b\rangle \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-i\chi\Delta t)^n}{n!}\langle0_b|(b+b^\dagger)^n|0_b\rangle $$
It's easy to see $\langle0_b|(b+b^\dagger)^n|0_b\rangle = 0$ for odd $n$.  To arrive
Eq. \eqref{8.127} one seems to need have $\langle0_b|(b+b^\dagger)^n|0_b\rangle = 1$ for all even $n$.  But this is not true since $\langle0_b|(b+b^\dagger)^4|0_b\rangle = 3$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I would guess the book is wrong: The result claimed there should be what you get when you truncate the environment Hilbert space to {|0>,|1>}. This is *different* from just considering the final 0 and 1 state, since in between, the system can be in any excited state. -- Indeed, one would NOT expect E0 and E1 together to be trace preserving, since the bath can be in higher excited states. -- Note, however, that if one looks at the *differential* noise (i.e. Lindbladians) from this noise model and integrates them (differently speaking, one measures the environment all the time), one would ...

Comment: ... get this E0.

Comment: Your equation that
\begin{equation}
\langle 0 \vert\left(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger\right)^{2m+1}\vert 0\rangle = 0 
\tag{Fr-01}
\end{equation}
is alright.

Comment: This is due to the fact that the state 
\begin{equation}
\left(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger\right)^{2m+1}\vert 0\rangle = \sum\limits_{\rho=1}^{\rho=2m+1}c_{\rho}\vert\rho\rangle = c_1\vert 1\rangle+c_3\vert 3\rangle+\cdots+c_{2m+1}\vert 2m+1\rangle
\tag{Fr-02}
\end{equation}
is orthogonal to $\:\vert 0\rangle\:$ as not containing this ground state.

Comment: Your equation that
\begin{equation}
\langle 0 \vert\left(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger\right)^4\vert 0\rangle = 3 
\tag{Fr-03}
\end{equation}
is also alright.

Comment: This is due to the fact that 
\begin{equation}
\left(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger\right)^4\vert 0\rangle = 3\vert 0\rangle+6\sqrt{2}\vert 2\rangle+2\sqrt{6}\vert 4\rangle
\tag{Fr-04}
\end{equation}

Comment: So your equation that
\begin{equation}
\left\langle 0 \left\vert\left(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger\right)^{2m}\right\vert 0\right\rangle = 1 
\tag{Fr-05}
\end{equation}
is false.